# prolog puzzle, can't find error

Tags: debugging, prolog, puzzle

Here's my code for my assignment, its not working correctly.
What it is supposed to do is take a family fact in the form of `family(Title,[Name/Speed|_])` as seen in the the first line of code and produce all the possible results of the well known bridge puzzle with the flashlight. However, all it says is true or false, depending on if the family fact is there or not. 
This program works perfectly fine if all the facts are laid out for example

`person(dad,1)
person(mom,2)
person(kid,5)
person(granny,10)`

when ^ is in the code, and the last `assert_family` is eliminated the code is good.
So it is something to do with the `assert_family` not being used correctly.

```
 family(original, [father/1,mother/2,child/5,granny/10]).

moveFamily(Key,Journey, TotalTime):-
      assert_family(Key),
      findall(Person+Time, person(Person, Time), Left),
      moveFamily(Left, [], Journey),
      findall(Time, member([Time|_], Journey), LTime),
      sumlist(LTime, TotalTime).

    moveFamily([P1-T1, P2-T2], _, [[T, [P1-P2]]]):-
      T is max(T1, T2).
    moveFamily(Left, Right, [[LT, [P1-P2]],[RT, [P3]]|Journey]):-
      select(P1-T1, Left, MLeft1),
      select(P2-T2, MLeft1, MLeft2),
      LT is max(T1, T2),
      select(P3-RT, [P1-T1,P2-T2|Right], MRight),
      moveFamily([P3-RT|MLeft2], MRight, Journey).

    :- dynamic person/2.
    assert_family(Key) :-
        family(Key,List),
        forall(member(N/V,List),
               assertz(person(N,V))).
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean exactly? You haven't told us what the assignment is or what isn't working, so it's impossible to tell you why. Please edit your question to provide the missing information so that there's a question here to be answered. When you do, please remember that we can't read your mind or see your assignments from here - all we know is what you tell us here. Thanks. :)

Comment: Should `Person+Time` not be `Person-Time`? That's the only problem I can see.

Answer (score 0):

```
% this seems to work:

% LPA WIN-PROLOG 4.010 on mac with WinOnX

family(original, [father/1,mother/2,child/5,granny/10]).

moveFamily(Key,Journey, TotalTime):-
      assert_family(Key),
      findall(Person-Time, person(Person, Time), Left), % changed+
      moveFamily(Left, [], Journey),
      findall(Time, member([Time|_], Journey), LTime),
      sumlist(LTime, TotalTime).

moveFamily([P1-T1, P2-T2], _, [[T, [P1-P2]]]):-
  T is max(T1, T2).

moveFamily(Left, Right, [[LT, [P1-P2]],[RT, [P3]]|Journey]):-
  select(P1-T1, Left, MLeft1),
  select(P2-T2, MLeft1, MLeft2),
  LT is max(T1, T2),
  select(P3-RT, [P1-T1,P2-T2|Right], MRight),
  moveFamily([P3-RT|MLeft2], MRight, Journey).

%:-dynamic(person/2).

assert_family(Key) :- dynamic(person/2),
    family(Key,List),
    forall(member(N/V,List),
           assertz(person(N,V))). 

select(H,[H|T],T).
select(X,[H|T],[H|T1]):-select(X,T,T1).

sumlist(L,Sum) :-
 sumlist(L,0,Sum).
sumlist([],Sum,Sum).
sumlist([H|T],Count,Sum) :-
 NewCount is Count + H,
 sumlist(T,NewCount,Sum).
```

Comment: Nice try, but add some info to present more effectively.